# Question on a variable passed to query

Tags: php, mysql

```
function add_new($father = 0 , $chName, $desc , $icon )  // add new category
{

$position  = $this->get_position($father);
$sql = "INSERT into ".$this->table_name."(position,c_name,c_desc,c_icon,c_group)
        VALUES('','".$chName."','".$desc."','".$icon."','".$this->Group."')";

mysql_query($sql) or die(trigger_error("<br><storng><u>MySQL Error:</u></strong><br>".mysql_error()."<br><br><storng><u>Query Used:</u></strong><br>".$sql."<br><br><storng><u>Info:</u></strong><br>",E_USER_ERROR));

$sql = "UPDATE ".$this->table_name."
        SET position = '$father'
        WHERE id = '".mysql_insert_id()."'";

mysql_query($sql) or die(trigger_error("<br><storng><u>MySQL Error:</u></strong><br>".mysql_error()."<br><br><storng><u>Query Used:</u></strong><br>".$sql."<br><br><storng><u>Info:</u></strong><br>",E_USER_ERROR));

}
```

Now my question is why does the UPDATE Query though works does not take the father variable. I am not sure whether its applicable.

Comment: You've misspelled <strong>. I can't help noticing the small things ;p

Comment: No wonder PHP gets such a bad rap for SQL injection attacks.  Take a look at `mysql_real_escape_string()`...

Comment: @gahooa yeah, it's all thanks to the magic quotes. (sigh)

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the `$position` variable - and I don't see why you're doing two queries:

```
function add_new($father, $chName, $desc, $icon)  // add new category
{
    $position  = $this->get_position($father);
    $sql = "INSERT into ".$this->table_name."(position,c_name,c_desc,c_icon,c_group)
        VALUES('" . $position . "','".$chName."','".$desc."','".$icon."','".$this->Group."')";

    mysql_query($sql) or die('snip');
}
```

Additinally, default parameters only make sense at the end of the parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

I believe variables having default values are to be placed at the end of the argument list.

```
function add_new($var1, $var2, $father = 0) { /*...*/ }
```

> "Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected."
>
> http://us.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php